# Batch File to save to Folder I created

Tags: batch-file

I have a Batch file as below

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do md "%%a_%%b_%%c"

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump -uroot gs > c:\%date%\gs.sql
```

I create the Folder with current date and time as what I want to do, but how do I set the dump folder to insert it in the current date and time folder

The above file runs but stops when I try and direct the folder to the one I created

I get the following error

```
C:\Trevor>C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump -uroot gs  04/14/2017\gs.sql 1>c:\Fri
Access is denied.
```

Comment: The folder you're creating is `Thu 04_13_2017` and then redirecting to folder `Thu 04/13/2017`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you were meant to do was this:

```bat
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=/" %%A IN ("%DATE%") DO SET "MYDATE=%%A_%%B_%%C"
IF NOT EXIST "C:\%MYDATE%\" MD "C:\%MYDATE%"
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump -uroot gs > "C:\%MYDATE%\gs.sql"
```

*Please be aware that `%DATE%` can change a lot from machine to machine, there is no way you can expect this to therefore work accross other machines.*